# Dependency injection with http Handler in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to wrap my head around dependency injection in Go, but really stuck here. Here's a (drastically simplified) app which should serve as an example:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    mux := mux.NewRouter()
    mux.Handle("/", myHandler()).Methods("GET")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", mux)
}

type myObject interface {
    Start()
}

type Object struct {
}

func (o *Object) Start() {
    // Something wild here, for example sending out an email,
    // query an external DB or something similar..
}

func myHandler() http.Handler {
    // Inject myObject-like struct somewhere here?
    o := Object{}
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        o.Start()
        w.Write([]byte("Started Object"))
    })
}
```

I have a problem with testing the Object struct. What I usually do is create an interface which can be used in testing by setting up a test struct. For instance, if I had a DB connection handler, in testing I can create a mock which satisfies the handler interface and pass this to the "myHandler" call as a parmeter.

Unfortunately this only works if the struct is already instantiated when the "mux.Handle" call is made. I simply don't see any simple way to test the myHandler function with an Object struct which can be injected in tests, since it will be created *after* the handler gets called.

Any hints or ideas on how to get this done? Maybe I have to rethink my testing approach, but I would really like to unit-test the Object struct, but also test the http handler separately (as this handler may perform more tasks than just creating the Object).

Comment: Why don't you make `myHandler` take an argument to create so you can customize the returned http.Handler?

Comment: So you are suggesting to pass a func to myHandler as a parameter? Jep, that might work, good idea. I'll give it a try.

Comment: you have a `myObject` interface, why not `myHandler(o myObject) http.Handler`? Isn't that why you made it an interface, so it can be swapped out?

Comment: Not sure if I understood that right: If I used the interface in the myHandler call, it would look something like this:
`mux := mux.NewRouter()
 mux.Handle("/", myHandler(???)).Methods("GET")`
What am I supposed to put in the parenthesis when setting up the handler? I could do something like this: 
`mux := mux.NewRouter()
 o := Object{}
mux.Handle("/", myHandler(o)).Methods("GET")`
But then I am creating the Object which is supposed to be created in the handler function.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now - you are absolutely right, I think I was overcomplicating things. Thanks again for your suggestions!